# Regex pattern for filename with date

Tags: python, regex

I have files with name "data_2021_03_v1.0.zip" in server.
When I tried using "data.*(ZIP|zip)" regex.It is loading all files starting with data string.
I want files containing only data(exactmatch-no extra words along with it) in filename.

Ex:
It is loading files with name "data_abc_efg_19-01-v2.0.zip" along with original file.
Can someone help to construct a regex pattern for above file format

Comment: not bale to understand your question`I want files containing only data(exactmatch-no extra words along with it) in filename.` what does this mean? does that mean you want data.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the pattern more specific

```
\bdata_\d{4}_\d{2}_v\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.(?:ZIP|zip)\b
```

- `\bdata_` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, then match `data_`
- `\d{4}_\d{2}_v` Match 4 digits `_` 2 digits `_v`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat a `.` and 1+ digits
- `\.(?:ZIP|zip)` Match either `.zip` or `.ZIP`
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PsCmGK/1)

You could make the pattern case insensitive, but then you would also match DATA for example

```
(?i)\bdata_\d{4}_\d{2}_v\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.zip\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sample I am assuming that all you need is : data_<number>_<version_info>.

Here is a regex for this:

```
data(_?\d)*(_v\d)?\.?\d\.(zip|ZIP)
```